# Two dictionary variables point to the same object however they affect eachother

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I noticed a behaviour from Python, where two dictionaries are affecting each-other, even though they are separate variables (and pointing to different memory location I guess). Below is a simple python3 script for PoC:

```
first_dict = {'hello' : '1', 'oops': '2'}
second_dict = first_dict

#let's delete a value from first_dict
del first_dict['hello']

#output of the second dictionary which is supposed to be unchanged
print(second_dict)
```

Output is:

```
{'oops': '2'}
```

What can I do so the second array doesn't get affected by the first array?

Comment: You have 2 references for **the same** object.

Comment: A suggested rephrase is "I noticed Python's **normal** behavior, where two dictionaries are affecting each other." Recall Python's assignment statement assigns a name to a memory location. Thus a program can interact with the contents of the memory location using the name. `second_dict = first_dict` assigns second_dict to the same memory location as first_dict. Changing one changes the other because the datastructure at the memory location is mutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not strange behavior. You're simply assigning a new variable to the same object.  This is the case for lists and I'm sure other iterable objects in Python.  But Here's the way around it.  Using `deepcopy()` ensures that any nested data also gets copied and thus an entirely new object in memory is created.

```
import copy

first_dict = {'hello' : '1', 'oops': '2'}
second_dict = copy.deepcopy(first_dict)


del first_dict['hello']


print(second_dict)
```

If I were to use `copy.copy()`, nested values would not be copied.  For example, try this out to see how it behaves:

```
import copy

first_dict = {
    'hello' : '1', 
    'oops': {
        'nested value': 'eh oh',
    },
}
second_dict = copy.copy(first_dict)

del first_dict['hello']
del first_dict['oops']['nested value']

print(second_dict)
```